# Can we see events in ganache?

Tags: events, ganache

I am using Ganache and wanted to understand where can we see the events in the Ganache UI. I tried checking the events in the transaction and logs tab but I did  not find it. Here is one sample code.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

contract Ballot {

    event isEOAOrNot(bool val);

    function isContract(address addr) returns (bool) {
       uint size;
       assembly { size := extcodesize(addr) }
       bool val = size > 0;
       isEOAOrNot(val);
       return val;
    }
}
```

Please let me know where can I see the events in the UI.

Answer (score 6):

#### Update 2020

Events are now available in the [2.1.0 release](https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache-core/releases/tag/v2.1.0).

---

#### Original Answer

It is not [currently possible](https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache-core/issues/45), but is on the roadmap.

Comment: now available in recently released (Jan 2019) 2.0.0-beta2 https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache-core/issues/45#issuecomment-455691740